# jQuery UI Portlet issue (cannot click on input box)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery UI Portlet
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

In one of the containers, I have created a form.

Now while the portlets move around and all that works fine, I have a form issue.

I cannot click on the form fields (input boxes) using mouse. I can tab through keyboard and enter data, but cannot click using mouse.

Is that some kind of a known issue ?

Comment: a jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: I'll not be able to do that since it's a huge page...but yes, just to give a clue, it is only a Firefox issue...

Comment: I have the same issue. (again only in Firefox)

Answer (score 1):

A little late - but I recently ran into this problem and haven't seen too many current solutions..

jQuery UI Sortable and Draggable both offer a 'cancel' option that you can pass in as follows to prevent sortable/draggable events from being bound to specified elements. For example, this will fix problems with being able to click into an input field when using draggable portlets.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  cancel: "a, button, #idName, .class-name"
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

If you still want to drag the portlet around using the form fields, you can try this, as mentioned on another thread:

```
$('.draggable input').click(function() {
  $(this).focus();
});
```